Max on the subarray of A = min on the subarray of B
Given two arrays a and b of length n. I need to find amount of pairs (l, r), 1 <= l <= r <= n such that max(a[l], ..., a[r]) = min(b[l], ..., b[r]).
I have this code:
int answer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int l = i;
            int r = l;
            while (r < n) {
                int a_t = query(A, l, r, false); \\ max on the segment
                int b_t = query(B, l, r, true); \\ min on the segment

                if (a_t == b_t) {
                    answer++;
                    r++;
                } else if (a_t > b_t) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    r++;
                }
            }
        }

It works for O(n^2), but is there a way to optimize it?

This amounts to 'please do this question for me' - "I have tried this and it has the wrong algorithmic complexity" is, in the context of leetcode style questions, completely useless - it's not the right answer nor is it useful as a basis (generally - and it's true here too, nested loops are not in any way involved in the answer you are looking for and not a single line of this code can be used). Hence, "Please do this question for me", and SO is not really meant for that. Generally you can search the web and find tons of answers, though - I'd try that :)

I removed the java tag.  It would attract close-voters, since you're not asking about java.

@Neil The question could be using 1-indexing. There are a quadratic number of subarrays, which is nowhere close to n!

@rzwitserloot Algorithm questions are not off-topic on Stack Overflow. In addition, most problems like these do not have readily-available solutions that can be found on the web, except the most basic ones. In fact, the main idea of the approach in the question is correct; it's just missing a specific data structure.

I wonder if an interval tree would be faster...

@Neil How would you propose applying an interval tree to this problem? It would be good to see alternate solutions.

You can do this in linear time using 2 monotonic queues and tracking the point where they cross.

I think it could be turned into a matching problem with two interval trees (max/min a/b) and a lookup table, since you're only interested in the count. But I think a simpler, faster solution already has been proposed.

By making the observation that max and min are monotonic with a fixed subarray starting index as the length increases, you can use binary search to find the range of end indexes that match the criteria. The range maximum or minimum can be found in O(1) with a sparse table after O(N log N) preprocessing.
Example implementation in Java with time complexity O(N log N):
public static int log2Floor(int x) {
    return 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(x);
}
public static long solve(int[] a, int[] b) {
    long res = 0;
    int log = log2Floor(a.length);
    int[][] stMax = new int[log + 1][a.length], stMin = new int[log + 1][b.length];
    stMax[0] = a;
    stMin[0] = b;
    for (int i = 1; i <= log; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j + (1 << i) <= a.length; j++) {
            stMax[i][j] = Math.max(stMax[i - 1][j], stMax[i - 1][j + (1 << (i - 1))]);
            stMin[i][j] = Math.min(stMin[i - 1][j], stMin[i - 1][j + (1 << (i - 1))]);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int l = i, r = a.length - 1;
        while (l <= r) {
            int mid = l + r >>> 1, logRange = log2Floor(mid - i + 1);
            int rangeMax = Math.max(stMax[logRange][i], stMax[logRange][mid - (1 << logRange) + 1]);
            int rangeMin = Math.min(stMin[logRange][i], stMin[logRange][mid - (1 << logRange) + 1]);
            if (rangeMax < rangeMin) l = mid + 1;
            else r = mid - 1;
        }
        int l2 = i, r2 = a.length - 1;
        while (l2 <= r2) {
            int mid = l2 + r2 >>> 1, logRange = log2Floor(mid - i + 1);
            int rangeMax = Math.max(stMax[logRange][i], stMax[logRange][mid - (1 << logRange) + 1]);
            int rangeMin = Math.min(stMin[logRange][i], stMin[logRange][mid - (1 << logRange) + 1]);
            if (rangeMax > rangeMin) r2 = mid - 1;
            else l2 = mid + 1;
        }
        res += r2 - l + 1;
    }
    return res;
}


Thank you! I used Sparse Table too in query, but didn't know how to optimize the answer loop. That's a great solution :)
